# Spring Data JPA Query - class projection containing another custom object

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hql, jpql

Suppose I have a `Foo` entity (fields: `id`, `name` and `barId`) and a `Bar` entity (fields: `id`, `age`), in a one-to-many relation. I want to select all the `Foo`s, having the corresponding Bar `age` attached.

I see 2 options, but none seems to work:

1. The so-called [closed projection approach](https://I%20need%20to%20select%20a%20complete%20object%20and%20one%20more%20field%20from%20the%20database%20(using%20a%20join%20on%20the%201-n%20relation)%20using%20Spring%20Data%20JPA%20@Query.)

```
@Query("select f as foo, b.age as age from Foo f inner join Bar b on f.barId = b.id")
List<FooWithAge> query1();
```

where FooWithAge is an **interface** having as methods `Foo getFoo()` and `Integer getAge()`;

2. The so-called [class projection approach](https://I%20need%20to%20select%20a%20complete%20object%20and%20one%20more%20field%20from%20the%20database%20(using%20a%20join%20on%20the%201-n%20relation)%20using%20Spring%20Data%20JPA%20@Query.)

```
@Query("select new FooWithAge(new Foo(f), b.age) from Foo f inner join Bar b on f.barId = b.id")
List<FooWithAge> query2();
```

where FooWithAge is a **class** having as fields `Foo foo` and `Integer age` and a *constructor that takes these 2 as parameters.*

None of these solutions seem to work. A third solution, of taking all the fields of Foo as parameters of the constructor of FooWithAge works, but I would like to find a cleaner solution.

Note: I cannot use anything else than vanilla Spring Data JPA queries. Native queries are excluded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For foo object you have to define a sub-interface:

```java
public interface FooWithAge {
 
    String getAge();
    FooView getFoo();
     
    interface FooView {
        //list of getters of foo
    }
}
```

2. In the first parameter you are creating a foo in a foo, so basically you have just to pass `f`:

```java
@Query("select new FooWithAge(f, b.age) from Foo f inner join Bar b on f.barId = b.id")
List<FooWithAge> query2();
```

Comment: I couldn't get the first solution working, but the improvement for 2 is very good. Thanks for reaching out!

Answer (score 0):

I faced almost a similar problem. However, I was not able to implement the second option because `JPA` was complaining about the `constructor`.

My not compiled variant

```
@Query("SELECT new FileProjection(f.id, f.fileName) FROM file f WHERE f.id IN :fileIds")
```

My work variant

```
@Query("SELECT f.id as id, f.fileName as fileName FROM file f WHERE f.id IN :fileIds")
```

My projection

```
public interface FileProjection {
    Long getId();
    String getFileName();
}
```