# JPA - add a field to existing entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

Say I have an entity class MyTable

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_table")
public class MyTable {

@Id
String a1

String a2

Double a3
...
```

and in only one query I need a new field on my entity class, that I get with a native query (it has to be a native query)

```
@Query(value = "select my_table.*, 1 as newCol from my_table", nativeQuery=true)
List<???> findExtraField();
```

my_table has a lot of columns, making it cumbersome to map each and every one.

How can I get the query to return an objet of type

```
class newObj {
  MyTable myTable;
  int newCol;
}
```

without having to map each and every field of MyTable ?

Comment: The new column will have a fixed value? Like you mentioned `1 as newCol` or will it be a data based on some query?

Comment: It will of course be a calculated data based on some other query, I put a fixed value just for simplification :)

Comment: Something like that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73540715/spring-data-jpa-query-class-projection-containing-another-custom-object

Comment: @TomStroemer, will that work with mapping an Entity and an extra field?

Comment: @TomStroemer exactly like that, I couldn't find that question with my searches before asking, I'm sorry. However that does not completely solve it, as the solution in that thread suggests we create an interface FooView (which would be MyTableView in my case). But MyTableView is not the same class as MyTable, so I'd still have to do a field to field thorough mapping to transform the view to the class, which I'm trying to avoid

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following, although you will have to fire one extra query.

I am assuming you to put a

```
@Transient
private int newCol;
```

into your MyTable Entity.

```
public void fetchAllData() {
        //fetch all your MyTable here
        List<MyTable> myTableList = emSlave.createNativeQuery("select my_table.* as newCol from my_table", MyTable.class)
                .getResultList();

        //this query will fetch just the table id from your MyTable and the new column you desire to bring out
        String secondQuery = "select my_table.id as tableId, 1 as newCol from my_table";
        
        List<Object[]> secondQueryResult = emSlave.createNativeQuery(secondQuery)
                .getResultList();
        
        //Collecting the result into a dto
        List<TempDataHolder> tempDataHolderList = secondQueryResult
                .stream()
                .map(o -> new TempDataHolder((Number) o[0], (Number) o[1]))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        //Collecting the TempDataHoler into a map
        Map<Integer, Integer> mapOfTableIdAndNewCol = tempDataHolderList
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(TempDataHolder::getTableId, TempDataHolder::getNewCol));

        //using a loop, fetch the value from Map and set into the extra column
        myTableList.forEach((mt) -> {
            mt.setNewCol(mapOfTableIdAndNewCol.get(mt.getId()));
        });
    }

    @Getter
    @Setter
    public class TempDataHolder {

        private int tableId;
        private int newCol;

        public TempDataHolder(Number tableId, Number newCol) {
            this.tableId = tableId.intValue();
            this.newCol = newCol == null ? 0 : newCol.intValue();
        }

    }
```

I am using the `TempDataHolder` just to make it easier. You can achieve your result without using any new DTO, just cast your `secondQueryResult` directly into `Map`.

If you exclusively want it to be casted on new class that you have mentioned.

```
public void fetchAllData() {
        //fetch all your MyTable here
        List<MyTable> myTableList = emSlave.createNativeQuery("select my_table.* as newCol from my_table", MyTable.class)
                .getResultList();

        //this query will fetch just the table id from your MyTable and the new column you desire to bring out
        String secondQuery = "select my_table.id as tableId, 1 as newCol from my_table";
        
        List<Object[]> secondQueryResult = emSlave.createNativeQuery(secondQuery)
                .getResultList();
        
        //Collecting the result into a dto
        List<TempDataHolder> tempDataHolderList = secondQueryResult
                .stream()
                .map(o -> new TempDataHolder((Number) o[0], (Number) o[1]))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        //Collecting the TempDataHoler into a map
        Map<Integer, Integer> mapOfTableIdAndNewCol = tempDataHolderList
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(TempDataHolder::getTableId, TempDataHolder::getNewCol));

       List<newObj> newObjList=new ArrayList<>(myTableList.size());
        
        for(MyTable mt : myTableList){
            newObjList.add(new newObj(mt, mapOfTableIdAndNewCol.get(mt.getId())));
        }
    }

    @Getter
    @Setter
    public class TempDataHolder {

        private int tableId;
        private int newCol;

        public TempDataHolder(Number tableId, Number newCol) {
            this.tableId = tableId.intValue();
            this.newCol = newCol == null ? 0 : newCol.intValue();
        }

    }

    @Getter
    @Setter
    class newObj {

        MyTable myTable;
        int newCol;

        public newObj(MyTable myTable, int newCol) {
            this.myTable = myTable;
            this.newCol = newCol;
        }
        
        
    }
```

Let me know if it worked. Good luck!